Is there any way to draw a circuitikz bipole component between two points, but closer to one end?
Circuitikz draws components with beautiful symmetry between the endpoints, but what if I don't want the component centered? If I want to move the resistor closer to the top or bottom in the diagram below, how would I do this?
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to [R] (1,5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see How do you accept an answer?). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Not the prettiest code but should do the trick:
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\drawR}[5]{
    \draw (#1,#2) -- ({(#3-#1)*#5},{(#4-#2)*#5}) to [R] (#3,#4);

}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \drawR{0}{0}{1}{5}{0.5}
    
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


Yes, basically this is it. One nitpick: you have the warning Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!  because you have a redundant ; (put it into the macro definition or in the macro usage, not in both)

Thanks. I corrected it.
